# How to pass which function should call in next screen after tap on button based on flow without using enum in IOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, enums

I am using MVVM Arch with RxSwift, I have one screen commonly used for more than 8 flows, Here I don't want to use enum and switch casses but I have to call different functions based on flow and route to different screens

Ex: I have Two classes A and B and both will go to C, Here C have one button with two functions Now once we navigate to C and I click button in C then it should call function related to A class and route to some other controller
How can I do this without enums

Mean I have to decide in A or B classes which function should call in C after clicking on button

Answer (score 1):

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    }

    @IBAction func btn_clicked(_ sender: Any) {

       let vc: ViewControllerC = 
       self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
        "ViewControllerC") as! ViewControllerC
       vc.isFrom = "A"
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
   }
 }

 class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }

    @IBAction func btn_clicked(_ sender: Any) {

       let vc: ViewControllerC = 
       self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
        "ViewControllerC") as! ViewControllerC
       vc.isFrom = "B"
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
   }
 }
class ViewControllerC: UIViewController {

    var isFrom = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     if isFrom == "A"{
        self.callForA()
      }else if isFrom == "B"{
        self.callForB()     
    }
  }

  func callForA(){
       //Your Code
  }
  func callForB(){
       //Your Code
  }

}
```

Comment: but it will only work for three `ViewController`s, here he has more than 8 flows as he mentioned in question

Comment: then he can add more if else condition as per his required number of screen

Comment: then it will become very complex intact in your way we can use enum as well but I don't need that

Comment: Finally I found some alternate for this 
I used delegates